# How far along is the anime compared with the manga?

Tags: one-piece

Episode 596 came out today, and I am having a hard time placing this in the manga's time-line.

Around which chapter would the anime be right now? And would watching the anime spoil the manga for me?

Comment: Can someone explain the reason this question was closed as "too localized?" It seems reasonable if you specify a frame of reference in the answer. E.g., as of Y date the anime is Q chapters away from the manga. (Mention fillers or anime orignal content, if applicable.)

Comment: @Krazer "Too Localized" isn't a perfect reason for this, but none of the close reasons seem to fit perfectly. The problem with this question, as it is written right now, is that answers become invalid quickly and need updating. If the question specified that he was interested in comparing them at a particular date then it would be fine. However, it's a problem to have a question where the correct answer changes. If there was only one answer I'd just edit that date in, but now that there are multiple answers I can't edit a date in without making at least one of them incorrect.

Comment: @RicardoValeriano This question was closed because the context and timeline of the question is constantly changing, therefore applicable only to "a specific moment in time." This most likely wouldn't help any future visitors. You may rephrase your question to be more specific (as of episode X), or to a general question about how much of a gap the One Piece anime production has in order to not catch up too quickly to the pace of the current manga. Please feel free to leave a comment if there are any concerns you wish to discuss.

Comment: @ʇosɥıuonʞʎonʞo If the question was posed more generally, than [this website](https://onepiece.d1g1t.net/) could be used as an answer. It's a website that matches the episodes to the chapters. So the answer would be useful over a long period (until it gets taken down on day).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to start reading the manga from where the anime is right now, the last thing you see in the anime is Luffy grabbing Caesar (episode 597), which corresponds to Chapter 670, page 19.

[image: Luffy grabbing Caesar]

The last manga chapter right now is Chapter 709 (710 will be coming out either today or tomorrow), so the anime is about 40 chapters behind the anime.

If you translate it into arcs, the anime right now is in the [Punk Hazard Arc](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Punk_Hazard_Arc) and the manga is in the [Dressrosa Arc](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Dressrosa_Arc).

Answer (score 3):

One Piece Anime is quite far behind the manga right now (about 50-75 chapters).

The manga is now in the Wano Arc, while the previous Punk Hazard arc just started in the anime (as of this answer).

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? How far behind is the the anime compared to the manga?

Comment: Wrong. The manga is now in the Dressrosa Arc, not the Wano Arc.

Comment: I'd hardly call that "quite far"

Answer (score 1):

It is really far behind. Probably in term of year, it could take more than a year (approx. 52 eps) for the anime to catch up with the manga.

In addition anime have **filler** episode sometimes between an arc, so it could be left more behind.